# Getting the size of a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, plot, picturebox

I'm creating a Windows Forms application. How do I capture the size of the windows form?

Currently I have something that looks like this in my code:

```
PictureBox display = new PictureBox();
display.Width = 360;
display.Height = 290;
this.Controls.Add(display);
display.Image = bmp;
```

However, the size of my display is hard-coded to a specific value.

I know that if I want to draw a square that re-sizes I can use something like this:

```
private Rectangle PlotArea;
private int offset = 30;
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    //// Calculate the location and size of the plot area
    //// within which we want to draw the graphics:

    Rectangle ChartArea = ClientRectangle;
    PlotArea = new Rectangle(ChartArea.Location, ChartArea.Size);

    PlotArea.Inflate(-offset, -offset);

    Draw PlotArea:
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, PlotArea);
}
```

Is there a way for me to use method one and grab the size of the form for Height and Width?

I've tried the following code, but it doesn't work...

```
PictureBox display = new PictureBox();
display.Width = ClientRectangle.Y;
display.Height = ClientRectangle.X;
this.Controls.Add(display);
display.Image = bmp;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
    PictureBox display = new PictureBox();
    display.Width = ClientRectangle.Width;
    display.Height = ClientRectangle.Height;
    this.Controls.Add(display);
    display.Image = bmp;
```

When you resize the window:

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Control control = (Control)sender;
   // set the PictureBox width and heigh here using control.Size.Height 
   // and control.Size.Width
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... i tried this but it doesn't re-size the lines when the form is being re-sized...

Answer (score 17):

For *Getting the size of a Windows Form*:

```
int formHeight = this.Height;
int formWidth = this.Width;
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to set `Dock = DockStyle.Fill` to dock the control to fill its parent.

Answer (score 3):

Set it to `ClientRectangle.Width`.

Comment: Hmmm I added an edit at the end of my code - is this what you meant i should try? If not please provide an example.

Comment: Did you read what you just wrote? `X` means the location, not the size.