# C# 'this.Width' or 'this.Height' is returned wrong after user resized the form

Tags: c#, winforms, size

I've got a "normal" form, the user may resize it and so on. 
If he clicks a specific button, the formBorderStyle is changed to "none", so that he may not resize it anymore and so that the form size is not dynamic anymore. 
After this happened, the code is supposed to return form Width & Height. I do this by using

```
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            mid.X = this.Width / 2;
            mid.Y = this.Height / 2;
```

Note: "mid" is just a normal Point.

**The problem:**

The code ALWAYS returns the size 1080; 720. This is because the starting size is like that. The code is supposed to deliver the changed size (e.g. if the user changes the form size to 2000; 1000 it should deliver 2000;1000, not 1080;720.
Why doesn't the program update the Size-values / Why are the old values delivered?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's the complete event that delivers the size:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Visible = false;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            mid.X = this.Width / 2;
            mid.Y = this.Height / 2;
            drawerUpdateSchedule.Start();
        }
```

Comment: On what event are you looking at your height and width?

Comment: Please show the code from the event where you are calling this code

Comment: `this.size.width/height` or `this.clientsize.width/height`

Comment: I did a test form and the properties `Width` and `Height` are giving me the 'Resized' value when I click the button. You should try to build a dummy form with just the button and a label to show your height and with on click event and see what's different from your original form..

Comment: That sounds pretty strange... Yeah I'll try it, thank you.

Comment: And make sure this isn't a problem with your `mid` variable..

Comment: Insert `Console.WriteLine(mid.ToString());` to check on the results. I can't reproduce your finding..

Comment: Okay, code's still not working.. mid variable seems to operate normally, I still don't have a clue why this happens...

Answer (score 0):

Check the accepted answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942939/getting-the-size-of-a-windows-form) thread, looks like an answer to your question. Especially

```
private void Form1_Resize(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   Control control = (Control)sender;
   //Access width and height withㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ
   control.Size.Height; 
   control.Size.Width;
}
```

Comment: This seems unlikely to be helpful.  If this event is attached to `Form1.Resize`, then there is no difference between using `this.Width` and `((Control)sender).Width`.  I.e. `sender == this`.